# Pushing returns through multiple depths of methods

Tags: java

This is probably going to get lost in the depths of StackOverflow, and is primarily an academic question, but I'm pretty curious and can't seem to find the right way to word this.

Here's my situation: I've got some method that relies on a certain set of conditions being true. It turns out, I have **several** methods that rely on those conditions being true. If those conditions are true, then nothing will be done, and `methodA()`, which requires the set of conditions, will continue execution. Otherwise, it will give a specific error, depending on which condition(s) is/are false, and ... we'll get to what else it does.

Since I have multiple methods needing this ***function***ality, I move it to it's own static function called `needs()`. I then insert the method call at the top of every method that **needs** those conditions to be met.

**Question:**  Is there any way to have some method force the calling method to return? so in my example, `needs()` would be causing `methodA()` to return without `methodA()` needing to do anything special aside from calling `needs()` in the first place.

Again, this is mostly academic.. I know there are easy ways to avoid this and get around it, but I'm wondering if you'd be able to do it. Please don't reply with "Why are you even trying to do this? Just do an if statement and have `needs()` return a `boolean`." I know. That's not my question, though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly but you can:

- Extract the methods to a separate interface and implement a wrapper that will perform checking and delegate the methods to the actual implementing class if the condition is met.

```
    interface Methods {
        void methodA();
        void methodB();
        void methodC();
    }

    class MethodsImpl implements Methods {
       ...
    }

    class ConditionalMethodsWrapper implements Methods {
        private final Methods delegate;

        ConditionalMethodsWrapper(Methods delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        } 

        boolean condition() {
          ...
        }

        void methodA() {
            if (condition()) {
                delegate.methodA();
            }
        }

        void methodB() {
            if (condition()) {
                delegate.methodB();
            }
        }

        void methodC() {
            if (condition()) {
                delegate.methodC();
            }
        }
    }
```

- Use dynamic proxies or aspects to perform the above.

Comment: +1 for answering the question even though the solution is more complicated than it's worth :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to directly control the behavior of the parent method (I don't mind any reflection hacks here) as the method knows everything only about itself (if you're not getting stack trace), but you may throw an `Exception` and add an empty `catch` clause.

Comment: Yeah, that was the best solution I could come up with as well. I could have all of the methods throw it one step further, even, which would effectively propagate that method back to its original caller.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if Java allowed for macros like in C :p